# Function not work after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function to renumbering list, on list i have delete button which call confirmation alert, after alert  function renumbering not work

This my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        numbering()
    });
    function numbering(){
        .....
    }

    $('#deletebtn, #addbtn').on('click', function(){
        numbering();
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone suggest me whats wrong with my script, thanks.

Comment: where is your alert ? post you full code.

Comment: Please show us complete related code of numbering()

Comment: its too long if i post in here

Comment: The real function might be long, but you should at least show us how the confirmation alert fits into the picture.

Comment: ok next time i will try, but this case solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the event binding inside of document ready,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   numbering();
   $('#deletebtn, #addbtn').on('click', numbering);
});

function numbering(){
    ..... 
}
```

Or if you want to put it outside the ready handler for sure, then you need to go with `event-delegation`

Comment: Yes! i would also like to see comment about this downvote.

Comment: @Jack Glad to help! :)

Comment: great answer deserves appreciation